# Garbled output of gcc

Tags: bash, gcc

I have several old Centos 7 compilation machines that are used automatically, but when I try a manual compilation on them I get some garbled output from gcc (and only gcc, no other command line tool seems to have the same problem):

```
$ gcc -v ...
...
/hoe/dargaud/Soource
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/toolslib/cuttctrl
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/toolslib/custctrl/custsupp
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/toolslib/prnnting
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/toolslib/tollbox
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/toolslib/lcaalui
/us/localcvi/naatinst/cvi2013/instr
/us/lib/gcc/x866_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/icllude
/us/local/incluude
/usr/icclude
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
comiled by GNU  C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), GMP vesion 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.00.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 6b72f3aacca5f1ab7626c11b21313352
LecroyHdoVisa.c:15:18: fatal error: visa.h: No such file or directory
#inlude <visa.hh>
```

It's like many lines have a middle part moved by one character to the left. It's just bizarre. I looked with a hex dump and there's no invisible chars (such as backspace) in the pipe. It's perfectly reproducible from one run to the next. It happens whether I'm logged via ssh or sitting in front of the machine (kde bash konsole). There's no mix of stderr and stdout, just stdout.

Any idea ?!?

Update:

- yes, it is from a wrapper, but I don't have access to its code:

```
$ file /usr/localcvi/natinst/cvi2013/cvicc
/usr/localcvi/natinst/cvi2013/cvicc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

- Scientific Linux 7.9, but I have the problem on other OSes as well, so it's most likely the wrapper. Also:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 22 10:57:56 CST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- for the hex dump I used `alias hd='od -Ax -tx1z -v'`

Comment: Without a [mre] telling others how to recreate the problem, you're unlikely to get a sure and certain answer.

Comment: ...that said, one place I would start is making sure you're _directly_ running a proper build of gcc, rather than a wrapper. `type gcc` will tell you if there are shell functions / aliases / etc in play, and whatever your distro is, its package manager will provide tools to compare installed binaries against their canonical hashes.

Comment: You run it `gcc -v ...`? That is, with the three dots? Otherwise, what is instead of the three dots?

Comment: (...ahh, you _are_ telling us the distro, and it's RPM-based. `rpm -qa | grep gcc | xargs -d $'\n' rpm --verify` is one place you might start then).

Comment: Also, `strace -f` is likewise your friend -- if you trace not just gcc but its child processes you can figure out (1) whether the unmunged/expected values exist somewher; and (2) at what point the munged/unexpected ones turn up.

Comment: For your hexdump, can you state the exact commands you are running to collect it, and the exact dump that you see?  I'd like to eliminate some kind of strange terminal behavior.

Comment: I updated the question with some answers...